# Cruise Control .NET force a task to run

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, task

How do I ensure that a given task always runs even if others fail?  Say I have a task that installs an msi, another that builds a solution file, and then another that uninstalls an msi.  If the middle task fails, I still want to uninstall the msi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Task blocks may be put into either the `<prebuild>` section, the `<tasks>` section, or the `<publishers>` section. Place any tasks that need to run even if another task fails into the `<publishers>` section.

Find the documentation [here](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Task+Blocks).